# flyway upgrade from 4.X to 5.x runs the already ran migration scripts again

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I was upgrading springboot 2 from 1.5. For that, I upgraded the flyway from 4.X to 5.24. When I run the springboot application after that, it's executing scripts which were already executed. Below is the logs I am seeing. removing project specific names as I am not allowed to post it:

```
myproject     INFO 2019-03-11T16:08:11-0400 main [org.flywaydb.core.internal.schemahistory.JdbcTableSchemaHistory] Creating Schema History table: "PUBLIC"."flyway_schema_history"
myproject     INFO 2019-03-11T16:08:11-0400 main [org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate] Current version of schema "PUBLIC": << Empty Schema >>
myproject     INFO 2019-03-11T16:08:11-0400 main [org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate] Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 1 - CREATE mything
myproject     ERROR 2019-03-11T16:08:11-0400 main [org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate] Migration of schema "PUBLIC" to version 1 - CREATE mything failed! Please restore backups and roll back database and code!
myproject     WARN 2019-03-11T16:08:11-0400 main [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException: 
Migration V1__CREATE_mything.sql failed
---------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42509
Error Code : -5509
Message    : type not found or user lacks privilege: SERIAL
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess You are using default value for parameter table.name, which changed in v. 5.0.0.

Refer to https://flywaydb.org/documentation/releaseNotes

[Issue 1848](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1848) The default for flyway.table has been changed from schema_version to flyway_schema_history